# How to do this query on laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Hello I have a query and it's hard to convert it into laravel style...

this is my query that is actually working directly on `phpmyadmin`...

```
SELECT id, 
            ( 
                6371 * acos( 
                    cos( radians(10.300563558355096) ) * 
                    cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                    cos( radians( lng ) - radians(123.87308120727539) ) + 
                    sin( radians(10.300563558355096) ) * 
                    sin( radians( lat ) ) 
                ) 
            ) AS distance 
            FROM rescue_units  WHERE type = "hospital" HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5;
```

and on my `Model`->`RescueUnit.php`

```
<?php

class RescueUnit extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'rescue_units';
    protected $fillable = array("name", "address", "lat", "lng", "email", "type");
}
```

just don't know If I had wrong on implementation... need suggestion on improvements...

Comment: You can use raw query http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Try something like this

$result = DB::select( 'SELECT id, (6371 * acos(cos( radians(10.300563558355096) ) * cos( radians( ? ) ) * cos( radians( ? ) - radians(123.87308120727539) ) + sin( radians(10.300563558355096) ) * sin( radians( ? ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM rescue_units  WHERE type = ? HAVING distance <  ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5',array(lat,lng,lat,"hospital",25));

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... I just found out what I want to do...

```
$lat = 10.300563558355096;
        $lng = 123.87308120727539;
        $type = "hospital";

        $markerByRadius = RescueUnit::select(
               DB::raw("*,
                             ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                               cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                               cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + 
                               sin( radians(?) ) *
                               sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                             ) AS distance"))
               ->whereRaw('type = ?')
               ->having("distance", "<", "25")
               ->orderBy("distance")
               ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat, $type])
               ->get();
        return $markerByRadius;
```

I just set the bindings below and same...